# How can I access all existing logging handlers in python?

Tags: python, logging

How can I can I find all logging handlers without exactly knowing the loggers they are attached to?

Is

```
import logging
logging._handlerList
```

safe?

Or do I really have to go through all loggers via

```
logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict.keys()
```

and grab the logger's handlers manually?

Comment: It seems like logging.Logger.manager.loggerDict is the best object to enumerate as its not marked with _ prefix which is less likely to be deprecated / changed. Today, in 2022, its still available for enumeration.

Comment: But multiple loggers will most likely have the exact same handlers, this seems like quite an overkill to just to get all handlers?